# Receiving invalid filename error when converting first page of pdf to jpg

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagick, hhvm

I'm using imagick to convert a pdf to a jpg in a script I have...it works fine if I give the direct path to the uploaded pdf without the page specified, but when I add the `[0]` onto the end of the file path to specify that I only want to read the first page, it bombs out with the following error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'Invalid filename provided' Imagick->readImage()"

I've also tried using `'/path/to/file.pdf[0]'` directly in the constructor with no luck, but without the page specifier, that also works fine.

According to the documentation...this should work.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
$doc_preview = new Imagick();
$doc_preview->setResolution(180,180);
$doc_preview->readImage('/path/to/file.pdf[0]');
$doc_preview->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$doc_preview->writeImage('/path/to/file.jpg');
$doc_preview->clear();
$doc_preview->destroy();
```

UPDATE:  I should have mentioned I am using HHVM. Not sure this would make a difference in this case...but I am.

UPDATE2: I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4771) over on the HHVM github repo.  Hopefully they will fix this bug...until then, the answer I have marked correct below is a decent (albeit hacky) workaround.

Comment: It's a bug. The feature is not supported, but repeated all over the PHP manual. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11114747/1163786 Solution using setIteratorIndex() over at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22673725/1163786

Comment: Good find...I figured it out by reading through all the supported methods...but still...it's unintuitive at best.  I also don't consider my solution a duplicate solution as I am not trying to iterate and produce multiple images...and therefore was unable to find that solution when searching earlier.

Comment: Sorry, Kevin - i didn't notice that this issue relates to the HHVM extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK...so the (kind of hacky) way to fix this in my situation is to use `fopen()` and then use `setIteratorIndex(0)` which is HIGLY unintuitive. But for those having the same problem...there you go!

```
$pdf_handle = fopen('/path/to/file.pdf', 'rb');

$doc_preview = new Imagick();
$doc_preview->setResolution(180,180);
$doc_preview->readImageFile($pdf_handle);
$doc_preview->setIteratorIndex(0);
$doc_preview->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$doc_preview->writeImage('/path/to/file.jpg');
$doc_preview->clear();
$doc_preview->destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have imagick in my computer but I can guess what the problem is. The problem is that when you open a PDF file with the page part you cannot include directory path string that includes the forward slash.
I think that because I read the readImage function page from php.net here http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php and they there don't include directory path so I suppose that that is a glich but continuing.
You should try to change directory to the PDF file using `chdir()`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) and then try the same function like this `$doc_preview->readImage('file.pdf[0]');` without the directory path. Most probably it will work.
Some API's have gliches and you have to work around them.

Comment: I appreciate the guess, but I'm not sure using `chdir()` is a good option.  If this really is the issue...that's a disappointing bug.

Answer (score 1):

readImage() requires that $filename is an absolute path.

If you want to use a relative path, then use realpath() on it, which turns the relative path into an absolute file path.

Instead of

```
$imagick->readImage('/path/to/file.pdf[0]');
```

try

```
$imagick->readImage(realpath("/path/to/file.pdf")."[0]");
```

Comment: Except I'm already using absolute server paths...not relative paths...which is why it works if I don't use the page specifier on the end.  The problem is with PHP/Imagemagick not accepting a filename with a page specifier if the path is also given...which seems to be a bug. It should accept the filename with page specifier or full path to file with page specifier, but it doesn't.  I'll test to be certain though.